# How to replace dash(-) with forward slash (/) but url should work as dash if possible in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am working on WordPress project and I have an URL like **www.example.com/compare-adt-vs-simplisafe.**

I want to make it like **www.example.com/compare/adt-vs-simplisafe.** no doubt I've done it with `.htaccess RewriteRule`, but I am getting the page not found the error. It seems like the request is fetching for comparing directory and resulting 404 error.

My question is how can we show dash as a forward slash in the URL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried that causes the 404 ?

Comment: well I've tried RewriteRule ^compare-(.+)$ compare/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

This will replace the first slash with a dash internally for any uri that's not a physical path. Put it before WPs Rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+) $1-$2 [NC]
```

If you only want it for uris starting with 'compare' you can remove the first capturing group:

```
RewriteRule ^compare/(.+) compare-$1 [NC]
```

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar Tried it and worked for me... Maybe it's a permalink settings issue.